# You must define an TOKBOX_API_KEY and TOKBOX_SECRET in the run-demo file

Tags: php, composer-php, video-streaming, opentok, tokbox

Hi I am trying to use tokbox video chat API integration on my website.

What I did:

I download their project from [tokbox php](https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php). Using composer I install required repository files and create vendor folder. Now according to their instruction I add api-key and secret-key in run-demo file and compile run-demo batch file using cmd. When I visit their server link `http://localhost:8080/session` Its shows `You must define an TOKBOX_API_KEY and TOKBOX_SECRET in the run-demo file`.

run-demo file

```
    #!/bin/sh

    if [ -z "$TOKBOX_API_KEY" ] || [ -z "$TOKBOX_SECRET" ]
    then
    export TOKBOX_API_KEY=<MY_API_KEY>
    export TOKBOX_SECRET=<MY_API_SECRET>
    fi

    if [ -d "storage" ]
    then
     rm -rf storage/
    fi

    php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t web web/index.php
```

and

```
    :: Why? because windows can't do an OR within the conditional
    IF NOT DEFINED TOKBOX_API_KEY GOTO defkeysecret
    IF NOT DEFINED TOKBOX_SECRET GOTO defkeysecret
    GOTO skipdef

    :defkeysecret

    SET TOKBOX_API_KEY=
    SET TOKBOX_SECRET=

    :skipdef

    RD /q /s storage

    php.exe -S localhost:8080 -t web web/index.php
```

How could I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use run-demo script ?

The run-demo file starts the PHP CLI development server (requires PHP >= 5.4) on port 8080. Start the server using the run-demo script: $ ./run-demo. 
You can refer this link for reference - https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yeah I did. When I open that url It showing that error.\

Comment: I added api-key and secret key...but its says `You must define an TOKBOX_API_KEY and TOKBOX_SECRET in the run-demo file`

Answer (score 0):

> Now according to their instruction I add api-key and secret-key in run-demo file and compile run-demo batch file using cmd.

It looks like you have editted the `run-demo` shell script for running on linux/mac, but you are running the windows batch file `run-demo.bat`. You need to add the api key and secret to that file: https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php/blob/master/run-demo.bat

`run-demo.bat`:

```
    :: Why? because windows can't do an OR within the conditional
IF NOT DEFINED TOKBOX_API_KEY GOTO defkeysecret
IF NOT DEFINED TOKBOX_SECRET GOTO defkeysecret
GOTO skipdef

:defkeysecret

SET TOKBOX_API_KEY=<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>
SET TOKBOX_SECRET=<YOUR_SECRET_HERE>

:skipdef

RD /q /s storage

php.exe -S localhost:8080 -t web web/index.php
```